# Very high cpu usage for trivial task | Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, cpu, performance, freeze, cpu-usage

Normally I do not post such question but this is a serious problem which I have found nowhere on internet. I will attach all necessary specs in image below as well as the key problem.

So the problem is that for any trivial task, like opening a new app, or loading a page on Google Chrome, the CPU usage shoots up to 90% and the program also starts freezing up. The problem is not for a particular app, it is same for any app, say Word or opening Start menu, or even resizing window.

Some images are attached highlighting the issue:

1. Normal idle pc:
   [image]
2. Opening word
   [image]
3. Opening chrome
   [image]
4. Opening notepad and resizing window
   [image]
   I have looked at other parameters like RAM and they seem pretty much stationary.

The specs are:

[image]

Specifically CPU:

[image]

RAM:

[image]

I have tried resetting chrome, but the problem seems universal for all apps. It is making pc become unusable.

Is this problem with Windows 10? What could be the problem and possible solutions?

Comment: Try to go to settings. Search for "Performance options", and try to setting it to "Adjust for best performance". See if this helps. It might be that the various graphics effects of Windows 10 are too much for your rather old CPU.

Comment: @1NN actually thank you it does give a significant speedup!

Comment: also, [this article](https://www.itpro.co.uk/operating-systems/26138/how-to-speed-up-windows-10) might be helpful. I'd start with the section "Disable services in Windows 10". Win 10 has a lot of services that won't really work on old hardware (such as tablet input, handwriting etc).

Comment: @1NN I am a bit unsure of which service to end as it may break the pc

Comment: 4GB of RAM on a modern and up to date Windows 10 PC may be somewhat less than optimal. Win10 is fine with that amount, but modern browsers and applications are memory hungry.

Comment: As other's have said, this is more or less normal, especially if your machine is underpowered.  And Windows 10 was released 10 _years_ after your machine's era - Microsoft doesn't design for that sort of thing - it'll _run_, yes, but not well.  However, one more tip in addition to what other's have said:  Check your virus/malware stuff.  That slows things down on application launch (especially off of HDD).  Can you get by with looser settings? Plus, it could be you're running more than one simultaneously (e.g., built-in Windows Defender _and_ something you've loaded).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's normal. Short spikes in CPU usage get the job done quickly. Your OS could schedule the process to take it slow and keep CPU usage lower, but it would need more time to complete. That makes things slower, not faster.

Your computer feels sluggish because you're using modern software on 12 years old hardware. If you could install software that was released in its era, wipe your memories of newer, faster computers and rollback the Internet to what it was back then, the computer would feel like new again.

Comment: Ok so that is true this PC actually is from 2009 so if I use older windows will it speed up? like windows 7

Comment: I think from  last para you are hinting towards buying a new pc

Comment: well.. ideally, the PC shouldn't "freeze", though. Maybe some tuning is enough to at least keep it responsive.

Comment: @jeea A new-ish computer would definitely perform better if specced sensibly. Installing Windows 7 is one option, although I would advice against it - Win7 isn't supported anymore and using it is not secure. You could give Linux a try if you don't mind learning it and don't rely on Windows-only software.

Comment: @1NN Yeah, maybe, if you're a tinkerer and have a lot of spare time on your hands. I've been there. I've learned a lot and the PC made it to its 11th birthday before giving up in smoke when I've swapped the Celeron for a Pentium III. But it's not really something I'd recommend for a daily driver computer that should _just work_.

Comment: In addition, though that CPU technically qualifies as being "windows 10 compatible" the graphics chipset does not. Last driver updates for it were back in 2012. As it also has just 4GB RAM (a fair chunk of which seems to be already used by the GPU) & an old spinny rust HD not only will it spend a considerable amount of its time paging to & from disk, it will be doing it at crawling speeds.

Comment: @jeea That level of CPU usage looks perfectly normal for your ancient CPU. You don't necessarily have to buy a _new_ laptop, but something _less old_ would certainly help! I happen to have a laptop from around the same era, and put a modern SSD in it. The CPU is so slow it can't keep up with the SSD even at SATA II speeds! Though it certainly is a lot faster than the spinning hard drive it replaced. So I'm saying you can only go so far with upgrading this thing, and you aren't likely to be satisfied with the result anyway. It's time for a new(er) computer.

Comment: What @Tetsujin said. Look at your disk usage while the CPU is high. You are probably hammering your swap space (on a slow disk). Upgrading to 8GB RAM should only cost about 50 USD and is probably the most cost effective thing you can change. (FWIW my Win10 PC only has a few browser windows and a PDF viewer open right now, and the RAM usage is around 6 GB).

Comment: @alephzero I think [this motherboard (?)](https://soggi.org/motherboards/msi-oem/MS-7525-VER-1.0-Boston-GL6.htm) is limited to 4 GB, at least officially. And it's DDR2, I highly doubt it would accept anything more than that.